# iOS - Google+ SignIn button when logged in - should it change to log out?

Tags: ios, google-plus, google-oauth

I was under assumption that image would change automatically to Sign Out if the user is logged in with Google+, but it does not?

Comment: if you look at the google+ sample app, they have integrated a log out button below the google+ sign in button. So I guess it doesn't and shouldn't change.

Answer (score 2):

It does not change - you should hide it after sign in.